# Global array only returns 0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have instantiated a global array called array and try append the values from dictionary to the array. I have successfully copied the values from the dictionary to the array but it seems to only locally. I am not sure where I have done wrong. Please help me figure it out. Here's the code :

```
class StudentTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var dict = Dictionary<String, String> ()
var array = [Dictionary<String, String>] ()
```

// Student

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     queryData()

}


func queryData ()-> (Int, [Dictionary<String, String>]) {
    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
    //var arr = []
    var count : Int
    count = 0
    userQuery?.whereKey("Type", equalTo:"student")
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects! {
            self.dict["firstName"] = object["firstName"] as! NSString as String
            self.dict["lastName"] =  object["lastName"] as! NSString as String
            self.dict["contact"] = object["contact"] as! NSString as String
            self.array.append(self.dict)
        }
        println(self.array)
        count = self.array.count
    })

 return(self.array.count, self.array)
// returns 0
// return empty array 
}
```

Here, self.array.count return 0 but I want to return the count of the dictionary members and the self.array only return empty array where I want it to return the dictionary.

I have been stuck on this for a while, I am not sure why it doesn't want to be global

Thanks

Comment: What do you think that findObjects***InBackground***WithBlock() does?

Comment: I am using the Parse framework. It returns the values for parse objects that is copied to my dict.

Comment: "...InBackground..." means that the method works *asynchronously*. It initiates the request and returns. The completion handler is called *later*, when the data has been fetched. – If you search for "return value from asynchronous function" then you should find quite similar questions with possible solutions.

Comment: I am successfully able to print all the members. println(self.array) inside the blocks works fine. I just want that array to be able to use outside the block.  So, as you are saying it cannot be made global this way?

Answer (score 0):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchronous, so when your method returns, the block hasn't even run yet. Instead, you need to call something in your block with the results. Here is an example of how to do this by passing a completion block.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    queryData {

      // update view
    }
  }


  func queryData(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
    var count : Int
    count = 0
    userQuery?.whereKey("Type", equalTo:"student")
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      for object in objects! {
        self.dict["firstName"] = object["firstName"] as! NSString as String
        self.dict["lastName"] =  object["lastName"] as! NSString as String
        self.dict["contact"] = object["contact"] as! NSString as String
        self.array.append(self.dict)
      }
      println(self.array)
      count = self.array.count
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
        completion()
      }
    })

    return(self.array.count, self.array)
  }
```

Comment: Thank  you Jacob. I have never done completion handler before and I appreciate your help to guide me to right solution.